# 'Only X left Threshold' for each product (not globally)

Tags: product

I would like to show 'Low Stock Notification' on my website.
I have set 'Only X left Threshold' globally.
Is there any possibility to set this for each product individually?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of concept, I would...

1. Create a module that generates a product attribute for low stock threshold (integer of course). Ensure the attribute can be set at the appropriate levels (global,  website,  store)
2. Extend the low threshold core model to include this attribute in the threshold check logic.

Keep in mind that the threshold is used in a few places - the low inventory RSS feed for example.

Answer (score 0):

Best way, go for @iUseMagentoNow solution. A quick and temporally solution would be to create an attribute *temp_qty_left* and use a conditional at the frontend

```
$qtyLeft = $_product->getData('temp_qty_left');
if($_product->getQty() < $qtyLeft) {
    echo 'Only' . $qtyLeft . ' left';
}
```